# Suckless surf + OpenWebRTC

Tags: browser, webrtc, openwebrtc, x-surf

I found out about OpenWebRTC and was wondering if there was a way to implement it in the suckless surf browser.
Does anyone know if this is possible and how I would go about it?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use OpenWebRTC, development has stopped and you will probably hit bugs. WebRTC has had some pretty big changes since development has stopped (PlanB -> Unified Plan) and mDNS candidates.

GStreamer itself now has [webrtcbin](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html?gi-language=c). There are also WebRTC implementations (webrtc.org, aiortc, pion) that can do media!

I would build the WebRTC integration out of process. You could write some IPC and let a 'WebRTC implementation' talk over a socket and exchange SDPs back and forth. I don't know surf's code that well to know how possible that is though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will look into it.

Comment: No problem! If you have any general WebRTC stuff always happy to help on the Pion Slack (even if you aren't using Pion)

Comment: @Fuseteam I honestly stopped looking into it.

Comment: @Chain ohw too bad